# Horizontally Centered Content with Space for Left Sidebar

Tags: css, layout

http://jsbin.com/uloyep/2

If you check out the link above you'll see that the .content is centered horizontally and a .side element is fixed positioned to the left of .content. However, if you resize the window/viewport down to 1024 or less, you'll notice that the .content (900px wide) is still centered in the body's 1024px width limit and the .side is cut off. What I'd like to design is a centered .content with space remaining on the left of .content for the .side element when the window's width is <= 1024px.

I've been playing with this for a while, and haven't been having any luck. I hope someone here would be more creative than me.

You can edit the source of this jsbin at http://jsbin.com/uloyep/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Check out my revision here: http://jsbin.com/uloyep/8/
Is this your desired effect?

I just set "float:left" on the .side and .content divs, and increased the width of the wrapper to accommodate them. Also removed the "position:fixed" and margin from the .side div, since the floating did the job.

Comment: This is not it exactly. Your revision does keep the .side from cutting off, but the .content isn't centered horizontally. Rather, the .side and .content combined is what is centered. I want only the .content to be centered and the .side to be on the left edge of the .content while keeping space on the left for the .side when the viewport is resized.

Answer (score 0):

How's this? You make wrapper fit around only your content then center align the contents.

http://jsbin.com/uloyep/31

---

Final answer: http://jsbin.com/uloyep/49/

Comment: That doesn't even center it seems. I'm on Chrome on Mac. http://cl.ly/image/1s193p1g1B37

Comment: The blue part needs to center, and the yellow part needs to be on the left side of the blue part.

Comment: Sorry I misread. I changed the link above. Is that what you're after?

Comment: That's not it either. The yellow element's right edge needs to be flush with the blue element's left edge.

Comment: I think you'll need to center both elements then offset the sidebar margin to make the body centered. Like this? http://jsbin.com/uloyep/45/

Comment: Already tried that. The problem with this is when you resize the window down below 1024 pixels, the sidebar gets cut off.

Comment: Sam you have it below but it can be done in css with media queries:http://jsbin.com/uloyep/49/

Comment: Ryan, cool, but how much browser support is there for this syntax?

Comment: Good for all modern browsers. Not IE8 or below. http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only way to achieve what I desire is with a little bit of JS.

http://jsbin.com/uloyep/47

All I did was gave the body element a .too-small class when the window/viewport is <= 1148px. I gave the .wrap element a 124px left margin when there is a .too-small class on the body. This works perfectly.

Why 1148 and not 1024 which is the body's min-width? Because 900 + 124 * 2 = 1148; But why 124 * 2? Well, 124 is how much space is on both side of the 900px wide .wrap element when it is centered and the viewport is 1148px wide. Once the viewport goes under 1148 width, then the space on both sides of the .wrap element would be < 124px which would make the .side element get cropped/cut-off. So, at this point, I give the .wrap element 124px left margin, and not the only part that will be cropped would be the right margin. I hope that makes sense. Play with it a little to see how it works.

If there is a pure CSS solution, I'm still interested. But, until then, this is the best I could come up with.